# Google Chrome Vue.js devtools: cannot install on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome-devtools, ubuntu-22.04

I try to install [Google Chrome Vue.js devtools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd) on my system `Ubuntu 22.04`, but the website does **not offer any install link**.
[image]

**Question**
How to install the extension on Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: This is not an Ubuntu issue. But more of a Google Chrome issue. Not sure why you have such UI but there is something wrong with that page (works fine on my side tho). Where, how are you using Chrome? Try on Firefox to see if they work there. Maybe give your Chrome a factory reset and update it to the latest version.

Comment: @kissu I've already installed the newest version (Version 109.0.5414.74 (Offizieller Build) ) (64-Bit)) directly from https://www.google.com/chrome/ (because of missing in Ubuntu Software). And yes, with Firefox the UI of the webpage is distinct (extended)

Comment: Do the devtools work in Firefox? Tried to factory reset and see if nothing or corrupted or alike? Maybe you have some network/admin restrictions? Do you have coworkers with the same issue?

Comment: @kissu yes it works on firefox